# TSLint enforce complete typedef on left side of assignment

Tags: typescript, tslint

In all other strongly typed languages I've seen, type definitions precede the value.  I would like to follow the same pattern in TypeScript by forcing a variable definition to have a full type definition preceding the `=`.

I believe I tried every possible configuration of `typedef` and `no-inferrable-types`, but I cannot get the linter to resolve this example as desired:

```
const f: (x: number) => number = (x) => x * x; // should be valid
const g = (x: number): number => x * x; // should be invalid
const n = 3; // should be valid
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue is. The second line of code is invalid because you are trying to declare a `const f` when there is already one declared a line above.

Comment: Sorry, they were meant to be specific cases of how the linter should judge style.  I have updated for clarity.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't quite understand it. Why should the second example be invalid and the third one valid? Both infer the type by the value you are assigning. `g` will be of type `(x: number) => number` just as `f`, because the compiler infers that based on you function definition you are assigning to `g`. `n` will of course be of type `number`.

Comment: As the associated tslint rule says, `const n: number = 3;` is overly terse.  Either [basic types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) or just primitive constants would not need type annotations.